# php preg match expression

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I wish to validate user input based on the following requirements:

- Must be alphanumeric
- Longer or equal to five characters

I have succeded with the above but two of my other requirements remains:

- Must have UTF8 characters åäöÅÄÖ
- Must allow dot and slash

  `if(!(preg_match('/^\w{5,}$/', $username))) { return true; }`

Can anyone help me extend this expression for my requirements?

Comment: [/\w.]{5,} to add dot and slash. Check here on UTF8 addition: http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html

Comment: It must HAVE åäöÅÄÖ or it must ALLOW åäöÅÄÖ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use unicode propeties:

```
if(!(preg_match('~^[\pL\pN./]{5,}$~u', $username))) { return true; }
```

`\pL` stands for any letter
`\pN`  stands for any number.

Comment: Great, didnt know those pL, pN existed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(!(preg_match('/^[\w.\/]{5,}$/u', $username))) { return true; }
```

Comment: I use dot in character class, so it's ok

Comment: Quote: Outside a character class, a dot in the pattern matches any one character in the subject (http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.dot.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9.\/]{5,}$/', $username))) { return true; }
```